# Solenoid : how dimensions ratio affects the magnetic field?

Tags: efficiency, magnetic-flux, electromagnet

For a constant length of copper wire (with constant diameter), how can I calculate the most efficient solenoid diameter/length ratio ?
(i.e. what ratio produces the strongest magnetic field, if the current through solenoid is constant)

Is there a general formula or some table for a rough estimation?
Coil has no core. (Air core)

Comment: Has it got a ferromagnetic core?

Comment: No. Just Air core

Comment: For a uniform magnetic medium, so all air or all iron, there is an optimum geometry for maximum inductance, which needless to say my google fu fails to find at the moment (begins with a 'W'??). It's something like 2:1 outer/inner radius, and as high as it's wide, IIRC, but I may be wrong. For a heterogenous magnetic medium, it depends very strongly on the geometry, and you need to sketch out the volume you need to magnetise, together with any other physical and electrical constraints to stand a chance of a relevant answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coil configuration which is most efficient in terms of length of wire is a Brooks coil. It is a multi-layer coil with a square cross section, and an inside diameter equal to half the outside diameter. That is, coil height = coil length = coil inner radius.

[This calculator](https://www.accelinstruments.com/Magnetic/Magnetic-field-calculator.html) allows one to calculate the magnetic field of a solenoid based upon its dimensions.

Comment: Ha! Brooks! I knew it began with 'w'!

Answer (score 0):

For a single turn you can use [this relationship](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/curloo.html) derived from the [Biot Savart law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/Biosav.html#c1): -

[image]

There is also a handy calculator that does the number crunching for you too. So, you get a single number for the flux density at some distance along the Z axis produced by current in the loop.

Then, if you have two current loops then the diameter has to halve and also the 2nd loop is a little further away from the "measurement point". Calculate two flux densities and add them together.

Rinse and repeat for the number of loops (turns) that you see as appropriate and plot a graph. Using a spreadsheet seems sensible.

At a certain distance away from the loop, I'll bet a single loop will be best but, that's just gut feeling. Close up to the loop, multiple loops will be best.